# Parse string " comes from a file " to integer

Tags: c, string, parsing, int

I am making a program in C that reads a line from file and displays this line on screen 
My homework requires that the file must get a number from the file and make some operations on it.

I get the file content and put it in an array:

```
while ( fgets ( line, sizeof line, file ) != NULL ) 
    {        
        strcpy(arra[i], line);
        printf("array ----> %d \n", arra[i]);
        i++;        
    }
```

how can I parse this content to int ?

Comment: Especially for homework, probably with `scanf`. For serious use, you frequently want to use something like `fgets` followed by `sscanf`.

Answer (score 3):

you can use atoi()

```
int x = atoi("string");
```

From your code sample

```
while ( fgets ( line, sizeof line, file ) != NULL ) 
{        
    strcpy(arra[i], line);
    printf("array ----> %d \n", atoi(arra[i]));
    i++;        
}
```

Comment: you need a name for your variable.

Comment: We hit the submit button at the exact same time. We're submit buddies now!

Comment: code is as sample only.. to show where's the int and where's the string

Comment: like that ??
    int arra[128] = atoi("string");

Comment: @Luchian: Do we get a Submit buddy badge ?

Comment: int i = atoi("1234") will give i a value of 1234

Comment: @Mahmoud no, the variable is not an array.

Comment: if i have more than one number in file

can't i parse a whole array .. ??

Comment: I think not, convert int by int, or read ints from your file instead of strings

Answer (score 3):

If `line` is a `char*`, you can use `atoi` to convert it to an integer.

```
printf("array ----> %d \n", atoi(line));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_DATA_SIZE 10

int main(){
    FILE *file;
    char line[128];
    int array[MAX_DATA_SIZE];
    int i,count,sum;

    file = fopen("data.txt","r");
/* data.txt:
100
201
5
-6
0
*/
    for(i=0; NULL!=fgets(line, sizeof(line), file); ++i){
        if(i == MAX_DATA_SIZE){
            fprintf(stderr,"exceeded the size of the array.\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        array[i]=atoi(line);
    }
    fclose(file);
    /*some operations */
    count = i;
    sum = 0;
    for(i=0;i<count;++i)
        sum += array[i];
    printf("%d\n",sum);

    return 0;
}
```